# Efficiency of Searching an Array Vs Searching in Text.... Which is Better?

Tags: php, arrays, search, text, performance

I have a List of (integer)ID's, which i am storing as text, like

```
23;45;67;12;332;783;123;33;15;87;41;422;88;58;
```

now i am working with PHP, i want to check if a particular ID already exists in that TEXT, i have the **explode** function, which can give me an **array of numbers**, and then i can use the **in_array** function, alternatively i can just use the **strpos** function to **find in text**.

so which one will be **more efficient** accourding to you ?

Thanks a lot for taking time to read this.

Comment: Did you try measuring the difference?

Comment: Sorry now i think i should have tried, but didnt. I just tried looking online for any results already available.

Comment: This'll also depend on whether you'll search one such string for integer multiple times, or only search each string one time.

Comment: I will be searching the string only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you have to do is look up a single ID, then `strpos()` will be more efficient, because all it has to do is find an occurrence of `id;`, whereas `explode()` will do a lot more than that, not to mention the costly call to `in_array()`.

Comment: Also, it should be considered that the amount of memory consumed by an array is way bigger that the memory used by a string.

Comment: Thanks, so strpos is the answer for me, since i search only once.

Comment: @Pheonix, definitely, if you just need to find it once, `strpos()` is much faster. Do however consider prefixing the string with a `;` so you can search for `;id;`, otherwise you will match `1;` even if you don't have the ID `1`, and have `11` instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, this probably saved me from some future trouble :)

Answer (score 4):

`strpos()` is pretty fast. However, if you combine `explode()` and `array_flip`, you get an array where all the keys are your ids, and you can just use `isset($keys[$id])`. This is gonna be faster since it's a direct lookup in a hash-table, but the explode + array_flip are costly, so it's only worth it if you do many lookups in the same data during one request.

Comment: thanks, your reply gave me some extra knowledge which i can probably use in future.