# strpos for arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have 90 'indexes' in my array and I have a function which checks if that value exists in that array, would it be faster if i used strpos with a String instead?

Instead of using `in_array()` to

```
$data = array('John','Mary','Steven');
```

It will be

```
$data = 'John.Mary.Steven';
```

then I'll just `strpos()` on that String?

Comment: Whats about `array('John','Lisa-Mary','Mary','Steven', 'Lisa');`? You definetely must take much more care about how you use `strpos()`, than `in_array()` here. OK, you may say "I add `.` at the beginning and the end and search for `.Mary.` instead, because there will never be names with `.`, but sooner or later you want to reuse it with other kind of values and you will hack around, just to get it working. Keep it clean! Keep it simple! :)

Answer (score 3):

Without bothering to profile it, I'd say that imploding to a string followed by strpos would be slower than PHP's built-in in_array() function.... because you're adding all the overhead of converting the entire array (all 90 elements) to a string before you can even use strpos(). Premature Micro-optimisation isn't a good idea, unless you really need it, and then you should test your ideas.

**EDIT**

If you're using your own function instead of in_array(), it probably is slower, but raises the question "why"?

Answer (score 2):

I was quite sure that use of `strpos` will be slower but I made a test below, and it looks like (at least in this particular case - searching for the last element) `strpos` is faster than `in_array`.

```
$array = array();

for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++) {
    $array[] = md5($i . date('now'));
}

$string = implode('.', $array);

$lastElement = $array[9999];

$start = microtime(TRUE);
$isit = in_array($lastElement, $array);
$end = microtime(TRUE);

echo ($end - $start) . PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(TRUE);
$pos = strpos($string, $lastElement);
$end = microtime(TRUE);

echo ($end - $start) . PHP_EOL;
```

Results I'm getting:

```
0.0012338161468506
0.00036406517028809
```

Comment: You're not including the high cost of $string = implode('.', $array); in your calculations.... if the data startpoint is an array, then you need to include that overhead

Comment: OP never said that this array is different each time he is checking for elements existence. `implode` may be calculated once, and output string may be used many times. But you are right, including `implode` into benchmark makes `strpos` method about 50% slower than `in_array`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this test](http://lixlpixel.org/php-benchmarks/search-array-values/), looping your array and checking with strpos() would be slower than just using in_array(). They claim that in_array() is actually 2.4 times faster than doing a foreach loop with strpos().

On the other hand, a question here on SO seems to indicate otherwise.

[Efficiency of Searching an Array Vs Searching in Text.... Which is Better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325128/efficiency-of-searching-an-array-vs-searching-in-text-which-is-better)

If I were you, I would run my own performance tests to see what works best with my specific set of data.